# iOS "Plugins" with sounds

Tags: ios, plugins, resources, package, bundle

Let's say a "plugin" is a collection of 5 sounds:
1.mp3 2.mp3 3.mp3 4.mp3 5.mp3

My app needs to support such plugins to switch between different sound-themes.

On Android ecosystem, I can simply create a new application that only contains those 5 mp3-files in the assets folder. It will be a plugin. Let's say its package name will be com.mysite.plugins.test

From my main application, I can list all installed apps (plugins) with package prefixes com.mysite.plugins.*. And easily access any of their assets.

I'm new to iOS world... And need something same. As far as I have researched, it's not possible... There can't be an app that contains only sounds, accessible from my main iOS app.

The only way seems to host sound-packages on my server (cloud) and download them from the main app.

However, this way requires payments for data transfer.

Am I missing some more elegant solution? Like hosting sound-packages directly on Apple servers?

Thank you!

Comment: yeah i dont think making separate apps that dont actually do anything but supply files in iOS will fly with apples review process. you would have to make a mechanism internally in your app to download the files needed

Comment: icloud may be able to host the files for you though and let the users download it in the app so you dont have to host it yourself, but im not sure

Comment: Hi @Fonix, thank you for your thoughts!